# How to move elements (home,features,pricing, dropdown linbaak) to the right side of navbar?

Tags: css, html

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

I want to pull-right home, features, pricing, and dropdown link  elements.
I was trying to add to ul class="pull-right" but its not working. 
I also tried to add nabar-right class to ul section also nothing.

Comment: pls add some description about your problem to question body

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap documentation:

> Align nav links, forms, buttons, or text, using the .navbar-left or
>   .navbar-right utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in
>   the specified direction. For example, to align nav links, put them in
>   a separate `<ul>` with the respective utility class applied.

So use the `.navbar-right` class on your `<ul>`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1s7j8srp/

Comment: unfortunately its not working for me. i'm using bootstrap 4  maybe thats why navbar-right /navbar-left not works ?

Comment: ok i already find out way to do it, I used justify-content-end class in div